# Показать div при выборе select с определенным названием

Tags: javascript

есть список

```
<select id="material">
<option value="0"></option>
<option value="рандом">Яблоко</option>
<option value="рандом">Груша</option>
```

Как сделать так чтобы при выборе Груша(именно по имени, а не по value), div id="prod" style="display: none;" переставал был скрытым и получал display: block
Спасибо!

Comment: А каждой опции соответствует свой блок? Тогда нет смысла их тыкать по id...

Comment: нет, только для опции Груша будет свой блок который нужно показать, для других опций блоков не будет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`select.options[select.selectedIndex].textContent` — текст выбранной опции.

```js
document.getElementById('material').addEventListener('change', function(){
  let isPear = (this.options[this.selectedIndex].textContent == "Груша" );
  document.getElementById('prod').style.display = isPear ? "block" : "none";
});
```

```html
<select id="material">
  <option value="0"></option>
  <option value="рандом">Яблоко</option>
  <option value="рандом" data="10">Груша</option>
</select>

<div id="prod" style="display: none; margin: 10px;">Груша, а вовсе не медведь!</div>
```

Но если код большой, со временем можно легко забыть, что привязка была к слову "Груша". Поэтому я бы как-то обозначил переключение через класс, чтобы уж точно знать, что происходит.

```js
document.getElementById('material').addEventListener('change', function(){
  let isPear = this.options[this.selectedIndex].classList.contains("js-show-prod" );
  document.getElementById('prod').style.display = isPear ? "block" : "none";
});
```

```html
<select id="material">
  <option value="0"></option>
  <option value="рандом">Яблоко</option>
  <option class="js-show-prod" value="рандом" data="10">Груша</option>
</select>

<div id="prod" style="display: none; margin: 10px;">Груша, а вовсе не медведь!</div>
```